# Accessing hashcode Without Triggering Hibernate Lazy Load

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, lazy-loading, hashcode

I'm having a bit of an issue with Hibernate that I'm hoping that someone can shine a light on. I have two entities, Product and Manufacturer, that have a Many-To-Many relationship. On the Product side, there is a Set of manufacturers defined as:

```
@ContainedIn
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "products_to_manufacturers", inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "manufacturer_id", referencedColumnName = "id") }, joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", referencedColumnName = "id") })
@OrderBy("name")
@AuditJoinTable(inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "manufacturer_id", referencedColumnName = "id") })
protected Set<Manufacturer> manufacturers;

public Set<Manufacturer> getManufacturers()
{
    if (manufacturers == null)
    {
        manufacturers = new HashSet<Manufacturer>();
    }
    return manufacturers;
}

public void setManufacturers(Set<Manufacturer> manufacturers)
{
    getManufacturers().clear();
    if (manufacturers != null)
    {
        getManufacturers().addAll(manufacturers);
    }
}

private Product updateProductMfgs(Product product, Set<BigInteger> mfgIds)
    {
        Set<Manufacturer> mfgs = new HashSet<Manufacturer>();
        if (mfgIds != null)
        {
            for (BigInteger mfgId : mfgIds)
            {
                Manufacturer mfg = entityManager.getReference(Manufacturer.class, mfgId);
                if (mfg != null)
                {
                    mfgs.add(mfg);
                }
            }
        }
        product.setManufacturers(mfgs);
        return product;
    }
```

I need to be able to call setManufacturers() without triggering lazy loading of the manufacturers. In theory this should work, but as soon as the HashSet tries to access the hashCode() method of Manufacturer it kicks off a lazy load for some reason. I looked at some articles about how hashCode and equals should be implemented (such as this one: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-implement-equals-hashcode-and-tostring-with-jpa-and-hibernate/ ) but none of the information I found is relevant. The lazy loading gets triggered simply by the call to hashCode(); it never actually reaches the implementation.

Does anyone have an idea for what I can do to solve this? Is there a setting or config option for hibernate somewhere that can modify the lazy loading behaviour?

**Update:**
Here is a stack trace for anyone who wants it

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy [com.tura.common.domain.Manufacturer#2] - no Session
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:309)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor.intercept(ByteBuddyInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.ProxyConfiguration$InterceptorDispatcher.intercept(ProxyConfiguration.java:95)
    at com.tura.common.domain.Manufacturer$HibernateProxy$cdTL8c5F.hashCode(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:338)
    at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:611)
    at java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:219)
    at com.tura.product.service.test.Test.testCreateNewFrame(Test.java:1793)
```

Comment: Could you explain why you have so strange `setManufacturers` implementation. Usually it should just replace reference for `protected Set<Manufacturer> manufacturers;`

Comment: @SternK This is a legacy application, so I'm not 100% sure. If I was to guess, I suspect it was to keep a level of isolation between the collection being passed in and the manufacturers field of Product. Whatever the case, I don't think it makes any difference to the issue I'm dealing with.

Comment: Try to replace your `setManufacturers` implementation by `this.manufacturers = manufacturers` and check what will happen

Comment: @SternK The code never even gets to the setManufacturers() method. It kicks off the lazy load and fails while populating the HasSet to pass in.

Comment: Can you share a stacktrace which call triggers the lazy loading? Maybe you just need to change the equals/hashCode implementation of `Manufacturer` to access just the id.

Comment: @ Christian Beikov I added a stacktrace to the post. As I mentioned earlier, it has nothing to do with the actual implementation of hashCode. The method call gets intercepted by hibernate and triggers a lazy load before the actual method gets invoked.